# R - Calculate "survival" business indicator

Tags: r

In R, I have a database with data for firms in a given month. The data is related to how much money they spent and how many transactions they made, etc. I only care about the firms id and the month of the observation:

```
month firm_id
3     333333
3     222222
3     111111
3     444444
3     555555
3     666666
4     111111
4     444444
4     555555
4     666666
4     888888
4     999999
4     000000
5     333333
5     222222
5     111111
5     999999
5     123456
6     333333
6     222222
6     111111
6     444444
6     555555
6     000000
6     999999
6     123456
```

The indicator I want to calculate is as follows: I want to 'tag' the new firms in each month, say in month 3, and count how many of these (as a % of total) are in month 4, 5, 6, and so on, for each month.

By 'new' I mean the ones that have not appeared in earlier months.

For example, in the example data, I have six firms in month 3. Four of them appear again in month 4, that is a 66.66%. Then only three appear in month 5, 50%. So on.

Then, in month four, there are three new firms. Of these, just one appears in month five, a 33.33%. Two of these appear in month 6, that is 66.66%, and so on.

In summary, I tag the new firms of month X, and see how many of these also spend money on months X+1, X+2, ..., X+n. Then for month X+1, etc.

What is a good way of doing this? I have tried a few things and looked online but none of the options have proven fruitful. Thanks.

EDIT: I am sharing data for the first month of the database, Sep/2016, and another one, Sep/2018, in the following OneDrive link:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!An8oTgObDW0Sk3P6WSTUR-WKDjHp

Thanks.

EDIT 2: I am adding the desired output, which I did not include when I first posted the question.

```
#  month next.month  prop.new
#1     3          4 0.6666667
#2     3          5 0.5000000
#3     3          6 0.8333333
#4     4          5 0.3333333
#5     4          6 0.6666667
#6     5          6 1.0000000
```

Comment: Consider including your desired output structure including expected values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated function. I bet there are much simpler ways of doing this but this one works.
Most of the work is to create a dataframe of the new `firm_id` in each month and then to compare those months with the previous ones.

```
funNewFirms <- function(firms){
  f <- function(x, y) {
    x <- unlist(x)
    y <- unlist(y)
    setdiff(y, x)
  }
  g <- function(x, y) {
    x <- unlist(x)
    y <- unlist(y)
    length(intersect(x, y))/length(x)
  }

  sp <- split(firms$firm_id, firms$month)

  new <- lapply(seq_along(sp)[-length(sp)], function(i){
    f(sp[[i]], sp[[i + 1]])
  })
  names(new) <- names(sp)[-1]
  newfirms <- data.frame(month = rep(names(new), lengths(new)),
                         firm_id = unlist(new), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  newfirms <- rbind(split(firms, firms$month)[[1]], newfirms)
  spnew <- split(newfirms$firm_id, newfirms$month)

  tmp <- lapply(seq_along(sp)[-length(sp)], function(i){
    inx <- seq_len(i)
    out <- sapply(seq_along(spnew)[-inx], function(j){
      g(spnew[[i]], sp[[j]])
    })
    names(out) <- names(sp)[-inx]
    out
  })
  names(tmp) <- names(sp)[-length(sp)]
  result <- data.frame(
    month = rep(names(tmp), lengths(tmp)),
    next.month = unlist(lapply(tmp, names)),
    prop.new = unlist(tmp)
  )
  row.names(result) <- NULL
  result
}

funNewFirms(firms)
#  month next.month  prop.new
#1     3          4 0.6666667
#2     3          5 0.5000000
#3     3          6 0.8333333
#4     4          5 0.3333333
#5     4          6 0.6666667
#6     5          6 1.0000000
```

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
firms <-
structure(list(month = c("3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", 
"6", "6", "6", "6", "6"), firm_id = c("333333", "222222", "111111", 
"444444", "555555", "666666", "111111", "444444", "555555", "666666", 
"888888", "999999", "000000", "333333", "222222", "111111", "999999", 
"123456", "333333", "222222", "111111", "444444", "555555", "000000", 
"999999", "123456")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

Comment: Thank you. Apparently there is an issue when creating the `newfirms` dataframe. It is treating some non-new firms as new, which messes with the calculations. In fact I have checked and there are many duplicates, this means that firms are being treated as new more than once. Maybe it is checking against just last month and not the entire period before, or something like that? A simple solution would be to keep the 'youngest' of the duplicates after creating that dataframe, although not very thorough. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.